# Product of two generalized hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there a formula that allows me to calculate this product:
$$\, _0F_1(;2;\text{ax}) \, _0F_1(;2;\text{bx})$$
Are there any references?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a general result, via which this can be cast in terms of the $_2F_1$ hypergeometric function. The relevant relation is formula 4.3.(12) on page 187 in "*Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol. 1*" by A. Erdelyi (Ed.), which I am reproducing below for your convenience.

$$
{}_{0}F_{1}(c;p z) \ {}_{0}F_{1}(c';q z)= \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \frac{(pz)^{n}}{n!\ (c)_{n}}\ \ {}_2F_{1}(1-c-n,-n; \ c'; \ \frac{q}{p}),
$$

The symbol in the denominator is the usual Pochhammer.

The product you seek is the even more special case of this, where $c = c'$.

Answer (score 4):

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_0F1), you will see that this hypergeometric function is very closely related to  the modified Bessel function of the first kind $$\, _0F_1(;2;a x)=\frac{I_1\left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{a} \sqrt{x}}$$ which makes $$\, _0F_1(;2;a x)\,\,\, _0F_1(;2;b x)=\frac{I_1\left(2 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{x}\right) I_1\left(2 \sqrt{b}
   \sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}\, x}$$ I do not think that you could further simplify.

Comment: Thank you vary much  for the answer. I know this relation, but my question is this: "is there a formula to reduce the product into another Hypergeometric Function?"

Comment: @AlessioBocci. I do not see any possible "simplification" to  another hypergeometric function. Sorry for that. Cheers.